# Speed problems in TCP Forwarding

Tags: networking, performance

I mounted a NAT server in a 16.04 ubuntu but when I sent packagesin TCP only achieved 150 Mbps of download and 200 Mbps of upload but  the transmission speed for UDP reached the 950 Mbps upload and download. The NAT server is made with a rule of IPTABLES (Masquerade). Is it possible a sysctl parameter affecting the forwarding speed?